# Hovering autocomplete suggestion makes element disapear

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a login form which shows itselfs when you hover over a link. So basicly, when you hover `a`, the form updates its rule `display: none` to `display: block`

When I start to fill the fields, the browser shows suggestions based on earlier inputs. But when I want to select the suggestion, the `element` sets itself to `display: none` again.

I don't want to set the `autocomplete="off"`.

***Suggestion shows itself***
[image]

***Whole form disappears when hovering the suggestion***
[image]

***Demonstration***

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: none;
}

div:hover form {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>Fill in a sample username and password, after that you get an fiddle error. Just reload the fiddle and then the autocomplete shows you suggestions</p>

<div class="hover">
  <span>HOVER TO SHOW LOGIN FORM</span>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: you may add autocomplete="off" attribute

Comment: All browsers same issue. IE, FF and Chrome. I dont want to set autocomplete="off"

Comment: the problem you are showing the form with hover and when autocompelte is opened it's no longer hovred, what about changing hover to click? or you need a js solution to test if autocompelte is opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that I'm removing hover when focus input
[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdx8ffqg/)

```
$('input').blur(function() {
   $('.wrapper').addClass('hover');
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('hover');
  });
```

**UPDATE**
You can add mouseleave also so hover class will be added once mouse is out of input
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdx8ffqg/1/)

```
$('input').blur(function() {
   $('.wrapper').addClass('hover');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $('.wrapper').addClass('hover');
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('hover');
  });
```

Comment: I excerly didn't want to use jQuery to fix it. Because im using angular with it. But it seems like its the only option :(

Comment: @Red  I'll try to find a plain javascript solution

Comment: No need, I just meant i wanted to use CSS only actualy. I know how to fix it using JavaScript. Just didnt want to use either of them. But thanks.

Comment: There is no css solution because there is no parent selector in css to change form display on focus

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, although you'd need to use a little bit of js and i don't think you can get around that issue without it.

i used jquery here for simplicity and just manipulated the css attribute, but you could also use vanilla js and add a class or something like that.

I also wrapped the form in another div while testing around, you probably don't  necessarily need that:

And i didn't change the display back when you click somewhere else, because honestly, that'll be annoying as hell if you already clicked the form and accidently click somewhere else and have it disappear.... but you could add that of course ;)

```js
$("form").click(()=>
{ 
      $(".hideForm").css("display","block");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hideForm {
  display: none;
}

div:hover .hideForm{
  display:block;
}
form {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}
div form {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Fill in a sample username and password, after that you get an fiddle error. Just reload the fiddle and then the autocomplete shows you suggestions</p>

<div class="hover">
  <span>HOVER TO SHOW LOGIN FORM</span>
  <div class="hideForm">
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The form isn't hidden when removing the cursor.

Comment: yeah, that's why i wrote "And i didn't change the display back when you click somewhere else[...]"